# Using downtime in an asyncio application

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have an `asyncio` based program which has very inconsistent CPU load. I need to do some relatively computation intensive things to fill up a buffer which the program reads from. However, if I do this while there's high load, I may end up causing the latency-sensitive parts to be slower than I'd like, as the "precompute the stuff" coroutine will be hogging a lot of CPU time. There are also coroutines that *must* run frequently (handling heartbeats for a websocket connection), so if this preprocessing takes too long those will die.

One solution I've come up with is to simply do this in another process which has lower priority, but if I could keep this all in a single program I'd be much happier. What is a good design for handling this sort of situation?

Comment: Have you tried using [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) to run the expensive computation in a different thread? It won't run any faster because of [the GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), but Python will ensure that asyncio gets its slice of the CPU, so your coroutines shouldn't starve.

Comment: That might do it. I'm not sure how priority is handled in such cases though. Say I spawn two extra threads this way. Will the main thread get about 1/3 of CPU time?

Comment: Python makes no guarantees of the kind you're asking about. Your best course of action is to try and see how it works for your use case.

Comment: @user4815162342 Ah okay, I'll give it a shot.